# Load textfile in sparse format using Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

I am new to Eigen and have limited experience in C++. I have a file which is represented in sparse format (like in LIBSVM) and I want to load the data into a matrix using Eigen. Can someone tell me how to do it ? If you can share your code, it will be really helpful.

So, the file has contents like :

1:13 4:56 9:1

2:45 3:12 5:12 7:2

I want to load this into a matrix using Eigen.

Answer (score 4):

You can use our [loadMarket](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/392d44b2d628d0eb1d4e55984f8f11b6a01c9dfd/unsupported/Eigen/src/SparseExtra/MarketIO.h?at=default#cl-133) function as an example. The market format looks like this:

```
%%MatrixMarket matrix coordinate real general
rows cols nnz
1 1 13
1 4 56
1 9 1
2 2 45
2 3 12
2 5 12
2 7 2
```

with rows, cols, and nnz replaced by the actual number of rows, columns and non-zeros.

Basically, the easiest is to fill a std::vector of triplet (i,j,value), and call SparseMatrix::setFromTriplets to create the sparse matrix.

Another approach would be to write a simple script transforming your format to the market format and call the Eigen's loadMarket function.

Comment: your example doesn't label the third col

Comment: Those are not labels, but they should be replaced by the actual number of rows and columns.